# fetch GET method. Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch, cross-domain

Данные с сервера могут быть обработаны только GET запросом. Ajax не могу использовать, т.к. с политикой проблемы.

```
let sentData = function () { 

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authentication': 'Token ' +  encodeAuth,
            'Content-Type':   "application/json",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'LINK'
        },
        body: 1,  
    };

    fetch("LINK", 
        requestOptions) 
    .then(response =>console.log(response))
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result) 
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
sentData()
```

Получаю ответ `file.html:38 error TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.`

Если написать POST, всё срабатывает, но данные в `result` = `undefined`

Где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: У get запросов нет тела. Body: 1 уберите :)

Comment: Буквально вчера отвечал https://qna.habr.com/answer?answer_id=1829237

Comment: Блин, спасибо за ответы) Всё работает, только получаю undefined в result, но это уже другой вопрос...